# Clarification on this Jasmine Error: this.http.get is not a function clarification

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

I keep running into this error when I try unit testing any of my functions that use a service in my component class. Here is a part of my function.

```
loadUser() {
this.httpService.getData(AppConfig.URL_UserById + "?UserID=" + this.userId)
  .catch((error: Response | any) => {
    this.showAlertWindow(this.exceptionMessage);
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  })
```

This part retrieves the data from a url and throws an error if there is a problem. getData is a service that makes a get request .I am just trying to test if the method showAlertWindow is being called. Now I am pretty sure my test code is correct but I have to be missing something to be receiving this error. I am guessing that jasmine does not know what to do with the line `this.httpService.getData(...)` Thank you.

Test:

```
  fit('should have getUsers() call showAlertWindow', () => {

 let window = spyOn(userComponent, 'showAlertWindow');

 userComponent.loadUser(); //Fails here

 expect(window).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

})

Full Error:

```
    Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.
Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.
    at SyncTestZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.SyncTestZoneSpec.onScheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:365:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:401:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:252:1)
    at scheduleResolveOrReject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:862:1)
    at ZoneAwarePromise.then (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:962:1)
    at ApplicationInitStatus.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:3580:1)
    at TestBed.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js.TestBed._initIfNeeded (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:1011:1)
    at TestBed.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js.TestBed.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:1050:1)
    at Function.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js.TestBed.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:834:1)
```

If somebody can give me some insight on the meaning behind this error, that would be great. Thanks.

Test config:

```
import { HttpService } from '../../services/http.service';
import { TestBed, async, inject, fakeAsync, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


    fdescribe('User Component', () => {
    let httpService: HttpService;
    let userComponent: UserComponent

beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UserComponent, 
      ],
 providers: [
  HttpService,
 ],
 }).compileComponents();
  });
   beforeEach(() => {
 userComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
 httpService = TestBed.get(HttpService);

 fit('should have getUsers() call showAlertWindow', () => {

     let window = spyOn(userComponent, 'showAlertWindow');

     userComponent.loadUser();

     expect(window).toHaveBeenCalled();


   })
```

Edit: There are two possible solutions. I solved the error by spying on my service and returning an observable. `spyOn(httpService, 'getData).and.returnValue(Observable.of('test'));` Or JanRecker's solution, which is more practical.

Comment: Please show your test configuration.

Comment: Updated question. Thank you.

Comment: You should also import `HttpClientModule` or `HttpModule` in your test spec.

Comment: Yes for brevity I left out some code and only posted what I am using with my current test. I have HttpModule imported. Correct me if I am wrong, but I do not believe I need to use HttpModule for this sort of test.

Comment: You do not need to import when you do not want to make an api call with http request. You are correct, we don't want to test http as a part of unit testing. In that case you would be mocking the service.

Comment: Can you post your full error please?

Comment: Sure thing I will update the post above with the full error from Karma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mock your HttpService ?

If you instantiated your service in the UnitTests, than it will try to process this method. I assume, that in your HttpService you use the Angular HTTPClient Service (i think so because of the error "this.http.get")

Now, you instantiated your Service, but not its dependancies. And, in the UnitTests, you have to instantiate everything by hand.
Therefore in your tests, there is no Angular "http" service up and running.

I have the habit to mock EVERYTHING away, that´s not my component/service under test.
So in your case i would do something like

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [YourComponentUnderTest],
    providers: [
        {provide: YourHttpService, useClass: MockYourHttpService} 
    ]
});
let httpService = TestBed.get(YourHttpService);
```

MockYourHttpService would be a skeleton that looks like the original service, but without fancy implementations.
Now you can mock that service as you like

```
spyOn(httpService, 'getData').and.returnValue(yourMockedData)
```

Alternatively you could import the HttpClientTestingModule, and mock the "this.http.get" call, but then your component Unit Test will implicitly test parts of your httpService.

warm regards

Comment: Yep you are correct. My component calls a service to get a URL that points to user data. Now I am only trying to test that my component is calling the correct methods. I am not trying to see if it is calling the service method. So showAlertWindow is a component function. Since I do not need my service, do you suggest create a mock service class with the same service names to avoid this error? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the mock service would be my solution. In the TestBed-Config you can mock a service with another class, see the "providers:[...]" part in my answer. The only relevant thing is, that the Mock-Class has the exact same public interface as the original service. (Or at least those parts of the interface you use in your component have to be the same). I have the habit to call my MockServices exactly like the original, only with a "Mock" before the name. Just to find them easily agin. :-)
Warm regards